# minecraft three entity spawner problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to make a spawner in minecraft that spawns 3 entities but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the command I have:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:cow",Passengers:[{id:"chicken",Passengers:[{id:"pig"}]}]},SpawnCount:10,SpawnRange:10,RequiredPlayerRange:100,Delay:2,MinSpawnDelay:1,MaxSpawnDelay:4,MaxNearbyEntities:100}
```

But it isn't working it makes it and there is a cow in it but I waited for about 5 minutes and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are using `/give` data instead of `/setblock` data.
If you want the give command here it is:

```
/give @p mob_spawner 1 0 {SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:cow",Passengers:[{id:"chicken",Passengers:[{id:"pig"}]}]},SpawnCount:10,SpawnRange:10,RequiredPlayerRange:100,Delay:2,MinSpawnDelay:1,MaxSpawnDelay:4,MaxNearbyEntities:100}
```

Thanks alot,
The_vikes